# Get row with the smallest time interval per value in a table

Tags: sql, postgresql, aggregate-functions, greatest-n-per-group

Here is my table:

```
Start Time            Stop time                 extension
----------------------------------------------------------
2014-03-03 10:00:00   2014-03-03 11:00:00         100
2014-03-03 10:00:00   2014-03-03 12:00:00         100
2014-03-05 10:00:00   2014-03-05 11:00:00         200
2014-03-03 10:00:00   2014-03-03 13:00:00         100
2014-03-05 10:00:00   2014-03-05 12:00:00         200
2014-03-05 10:00:00   2014-03-05 13:00:00         200
```

I want to get the smallest time interval for each extension:

```
Start Time            Stop time                  Extension
-------------------------------------------------------------
2014-03-03 10:00:00   2014-03-03 11:00:00         100
2014-03-05 10:00:00   2014-03-05 11:00:00         200
```

How can I write the sql?

Comment: Get the single smallest time interval in the table or the smallest time interval for each start or something?

Comment: Now all we need is Craig Ringer to pitch in and @gameip has all the PostgreSQL high-hitters assembled in one post before even hitting 10 rep. Surely there must be a gold badge for that??? -[;-D

Comment: The question is unclear: you need the smallest interval, or the row with the min interval? (Or something else?)

Comment: I have added more details about the questions. In fact, it's not only get one record. I want to get the result according to extension. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To get the row (including all original columns) with the smallest time interval for each `extension` (according to your *updated* question) the Postgres specific `DISTINCT ON` should be most convenient:

```
SELECT DISTINCT ON (extension)
       start_time, stop_time, extension
FROM   tbl
ORDER  BY extension, (stop_time - start_time);
```

Details in this related answer:
[Select first row in each GROUP BY group?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3800551/select-first-row-in-each-group-by-group/7630564#7630564)

Answer (score 1):

not sure what exactly you are after, but the "smallest interval" would be

```
select min(stop_time - start_time) 
from the_table
```

If you also need the two columns with that:

```
select start_time, stop_time, duration
from (
   select start_time, 
          stop_time,
          stop_time - start_time as duration,
          min(stop_time - start_time) as min_duration
   from the_table
) t
where duration = min_duration;
```

The above would yield more than one row if multiple rows have the same duration. If you don't want that you can use:

```
select start_time, stop_time, duration
from (
   select start_time, 
          stop_time,
          stop_time - start_time as duration,
          row_numer() over (order by stop_time - start_time) as rn
   from the_table
) t
where rn = 1;
```

Answer (score 1):

```
CREATE TABLE fluff
        ( id SERIAL NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY
        , starttime TIMESTAMP NOT NULL
        , stoptime TIMESTAMP NOT NULL
        );

INSERT INTO fluff(starttime,stoptime) VALUES
  ('2014-03-03 10:00:00' , '2014-03-03 11:00:00' )
, ('2014-03-03 10:00:00' , '2014-03-03 12:00:00' )
, ('2014-03-03 10:00:00' , '2014-03-03 13:00:00' )
        ;

SELECT * FROM fluff fl
WHERE NOT EXISTS (
        SELECT *
        FROM fluff nx
        WHERE AGE(nx.stoptime,nx.starttime) < AGE(fl.stoptime,fl.starttime)
        );
```

Okay, After the update:

```
CREATE TABLE fluff2
        ( id SERIAL NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY
        , starttime TIMESTAMP NOT NULL
        , stoptime TIMESTAMP NOT NULL
        , bagger INTEGER NOT NULL
        );
;

INSERT INTO fluff2(starttime,stoptime, bagger) VALUES
  ( '2014-03-03 10:00:00', '2014-03-03 11:00:00',100)
, ( '2014-03-03 10:00:00', '2014-03-03 12:00:00',100)
, ( '2014-03-05 10:00:00', '2014-03-05 11:00:00',200)
, ( '2014-03-03 10:00:00', '2014-03-03 13:00:00',100)
, ( '2014-03-05 10:00:00', '2014-03-05 12:00:00',200)
, ( '2014-03-05 10:00:00', '2014-03-05 13:00:00',200)
        ;

SELECT * FROM fluff2 fl
WHERE NOT EXISTS (
        SELECT *
        FROM fluff2 nx
        WHERE nx.bagger = fl.bagger
        AND AGE(nx.stoptime,nx.starttime) < AGE(fl.stoptime,fl.starttime)
        );
```

Answer (score 0):

I would use `order by` and `limit`:

```
select t.*
from table t
order by stop_time - start_time asc
limit 1;
```

This gives you all the columns in the table for the smallest duration.